# Почему \a не звонит?

Tags: c++

Почему `\a` не звонит?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << '\a';
}
```

Comment: А спикер к материнке подключен ?

Comment: @Mike не знаю, как это проверить?

Comment: C++ вообще ни разу ни при чём, звонить или не звонить это забота используемого вами терминала

Comment: @Abyx собственно про это и вопрос * ba-dum-tss *

Comment: @Abyx а что может быть не так?

Comment: Динамики включены? Просто звук воспроизводится?

Comment: @Harry да, музыка играет в наушниках

Comment: Ну вот только что откомпилировал VC++2015, запустил и в наушниках пикнуло :)

Comment: @Harry у меня ни g++, ни VC++17 не пикает

Comment: @matvey Музыка в наушниках выводится звуковой картой. а стандартный терминал звук выводит на системный динамик, который висит на отдельном разъеме на материнской плате. или вообще припаян к матери. И да, это зависит от терминала на котором вы запускаете программу. В общем для начала ищете описание на мать, смотрите где на ней speaker разведен, разбираете комп, убеждаетесь что к этому месту что то подключено, и оно способно издавать звуки. потом грузитесь в DOS, что бы точно ничего не стояло между вашей программой и железом и пробуете. В общем итог: забейте, дался вам этот звук от `\a`

Comment: @Mike Ваш комментарий достоин преобразования в ответ. Что происходит с PC-спикером в современном мире — не так тривиально, и, если ничего не изменилось, пикание имеет значение во время загрузки, например.

Comment: Я б предположил, что поиски надо начинать скорее со средства, занимающегося выводом, поскольку оно может определять вывод этого "символа" по-своему, в т. ч. на обычные колонки вместо динамика на материнке. Консоль винды, конкретный эмулятор терминала, и т. д.

Comment: @D-side пробовал и в винде и в линуксе на виртуалбоксе

Comment: @Mike: что делает `cout << '\a'` от окружения зависит. К примеру, в gnome-terminal `printf '\a'` у меня никакого звука не создаёт, а та же команда в Linux консоле (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>) уже beep выдаёт ([разные механизмы используются (PulseAudio  vs. pcspkr)](https://askubuntu.com/a/587311/3712). Ещё пример, если код в контексте сервиса выполняется (к примеру, `rc-local.service`), то ещё [от StandardOutput настройки может зависеть](https://askubuntu.com/a/837181/3712))

Answer (score 1):

Всё, получилось, просто из `IDE` звука нет. А если отдельно запустить приложение, то есть

Comment: Дело в том, что программа в данном случае успевает завершиться _раньше_, чем вы услышите сигнал..

Comment: @Nikita нет, я считываю потом данные